# How do I refer to an object before the property "style.backgroundcolor"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I refer to an object before the property "style.backgroundcolor"? In other words, what can I do to be able to put "pos[0].placement" before "style.backgroundColor = "red";"? I guess I get an error because of the excessive dots.

```
var pos = [
  {placement: "enEl", value: 0},
  {placement: "toEl", value: 0},
  {placement: "treEl", value: 0},
  {placement: "fireEl", value: 0},
  {placement: "femEl", value: 0},
  {placement: "seksEl", value: 0}
];

pos[0].placement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: `pos[0].placement` is a string, not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of identifier is `placement`? It seems like you want to use something like `document.getElementByXYZ()` to get a dom node. There you have a style attribute containing backgroundColor. For technical reasons there's no such thing like 'excessive dots'. (For code style and design principle reasons there is :) )